# .NET FileLoadException

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

NET, on the following line:

```
Dim shellFile As ShellFile = shellFile.FromFilePath(tmpFile)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly '[Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack),
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I did read some suggestions as to what the issue could be, but none of them seemed to help me, and I think the errors were slightly different, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you tell us what you DID try, though? This will help guide newer answers

Comment: You get this error when running on the deployment machine, rather than your development machine?  The exception seems pretty descriptive.

Comment: You simply got the wrong version of the assembly.  Get the right version.  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4906

Comment: Art, I removed my comment if you would like to just delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

update your assemblies and .net framework